# Был ли раньше «приятный аппетит»?

Tags: этимология, история-языка, idioms

Есть пожелание «Приятного аппетита», но нет словосочетания «приятный аппетит».
Почему так?
Это устаревшее?

Comment: Возможно пожелание было дословно переведено c французского Bon Appétit и не имеет никакой предыстории в русском языке.

Comment: @Artemix Более чем вероятно. Но тогда надо пояснять, почему _bon_ → именно _приятный_, а не _хороший_, например, или довольно типичное для формул этикета _добрый_.

Comment: Если заменить "добрый" на "приятный" получится что-то из сферы обслуживания или развлечений: "приятного просмотра" (в кино), "приятного вечера". Ну и формулы знакомства "приятно познакомиться", "очень приятно". Вот еще отсылка к ["приятно кушать"](http://www.rg.ru/2004/07/30/korolyova.html/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словосочетание *приятный аппетит*, хотя и редкое, находится [ruscorpora.ru](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%F0%E8%FF%F2%ED%FB%E9%20%E0%EF%EF%E5%F2%E8%F2).   Согласно Корпусу, *приятного аппетита* встречается с 1869 года, *приятный аппетит* - с 1901, а *приятного сна* - с XVIII века.  Так что *приятного аппетита*, вероятно, возникло, когда *Bon Appétit* перевели по аналогии с *приятного сна*, а уж от него произошёл *приятный аппетит*.